# Scroll к элементу на странице без якорной ссылки( не использовать id для привязки)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите по возможным вариантам решения следующей задачи.
На странице есть сайдбар с пунктами меню при нажатии на пункт меню происходит скролл к соответствующему разделу на странице.  Проблема в том что пункты меню меню могут меняться добавлятьсявведите сюда код и контент тоже. Я хотел сделать чтоб скролл происходил к заголовку с таким же текстом на странице.  Что-то типа такого " кликнул на пункт меню, получил его текст, и проскролил до такого же текста в контенте страницы"

Вот такая примерно структура страницы https://jsfiddle.net/8ue02gud/2/

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="">test1</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test2</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test3</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test4</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="content" id="viewer">
  <li>
    <h2>test1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
    <li>
    <h2>test2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
    <li>
    <h2>test3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
    <li>
    <h2>test4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

.container{
  display: flex;
}
.menu{
  width:15%;
  list-style-type:none;

}
.item a{
  color:8C8757;
}

.content{
  width:85%;
}

.content li::nth-child(odd){
  background-color:#8C8475;
}
h2{
  color:#8C6D8A;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, Вы сами описали, что нужно сделать: "кликнул на пункт меню, получил его текст, и проскролил до такого же текста в контенте страницы".

```js
$(".item a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var h2Offset;
  var linkText = $(this).html();
  $("h2").each(function() {
    var h2This = $(this);
    if ($(h2This).html() == linkText) {
      h2Offset = $(h2This).offset().top;
    }
  });

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: h2Offset
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.menu{
  width:15%;
  list-style-type:none;
  
}
.item a{
  color:8C8757;
}

.content{
  width:85%;
}

.content li::nth-child(odd){
  background-color:#8C8475;
}
h2{
  color:#8C6D8A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="">test1</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test2</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test3</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test4</a>
  </li>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="">test5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="content" id="viewer">
  <li>
    <h2>test1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
    <li>
    <h2>test2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
    <li>
    <h2>test3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
    <li>
    <h2>test4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita rerum voluptates, sequi autem sint cupiditate a nihil quae rem ullam dolorem maiores corrupti laborum earum possimus, accusamus voluptate dicta veritatis!</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```